# Navigation Buttons + UICollectionview on same controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios7.1

I'm newbie with iOS and asking for direction.

I want to make a page which contains navigation buttons on top and when tap load different `UICollectionView`'s as you can see on the app screen taken from "Fancy". Also buttons line have to be fixed on top while scrolling down. (just like in the screenshot)

Which is the right approach?

1. Base class to be `UICollectionViewController` and adding as SubView
2. Using UIScrollViewController?

etc...

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There isnt anything like UIScrollViewController in iOS Sdk. Use either UICollectionViewController or use UIViewController and add UICollectionView as a subview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base class should be `UiViewController` implementing `UICollectionViewDelegate`

```
UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

Create different `NSArray` for each Category of your project as datasource of `UICollectionView`

use `UISegmentedControl` for switching the datasource of `UICollectionView` and reload `UICollectionView` to display different content.
You can customise your `Segmented Control` as you wanted.

Implement `UITabbarController` for the bottom bar to enter any other views

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to go about this. The simplest would probably be to use a `UIViewController` subclass whose `view` contains a `UISegmentedControl` subview (for the navigation controls) and a `UICollectionView` subview for the content.

Comment: is it possible to set custom design to UISegmentedControl?